# Getting Warnings with Role Reaction in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hey I recently started programming a discord bot. But now I have a problem. I'm trying to get a role reaction but somehow I keep getting errors. I'm going to link you errors and my code so maybe someone can help me.

**Warnings:** https://hastebin.com/ativekefod.sql

**MessageReactionAddEvent.js:** https://hastebin.com/nababomuta.js

*Thanks for any help!*

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are retrieving 3 parameters when only 2 are given, `messageReaction` and `user`,

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd

So essentially you are calling .message on a user class.

Change the run function to:

```js
async run(client, reaction, user);
```

And then your message variable would be:

```js
const message = reaction.message;
```

It's possible it's different depending on your event handler but this is most likely it

Comment: Now I get "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" for "["", ""].includes(reaction.message.emoji.name)"

Comment: you aren't supposed to get the emoji by the message class, that would not make sense since there can be multiple emojis on it, just call `reaction.emoji.name` instead.

Comment: Very cool it works thanks but now I have to figure out how to write it into a database so that I don't have to create a new embed every time I restart the bot. Let's see if I can find a video for that because I have absolutely no idea how to do that. :D

Comment: A database isn't a good solution,  either way you will need to create a new embed since the embed isn't static, it changes depending on the emoji.